# programmatically check if today is a market open trading day

Tags: stock, algorithmic-trading

What might be the simplest way to check if today the U.S. stock exchanges are open for trading?

The prolonged way I am hoping to avoid is by creating routines to parse a feed with calendar info like https://business.nasdaq.com/trade/US-Options/Holiday-Trading-Hours.html

I prefer **Ruby**, but even a simple URL lookup with **curl** to yield a true/false, or time until next market open, would be great.

OPTIONAL

To be able to lookup any arbitrary date would be better, and solve this too.
I.e. Even something like `curl google.com/search?q="Is the NYSE open on $(date +%Y-%m-%d)"` from the shell.

Comment: Related (not identical) questions have been found here, but usually domain-specific (eg. Matlab, R, requiring libraries, fat API or infrastructure, etc.) or not adequately solved.

Comment: so given the answer (user crappy_hacker) currently given is it worth clarifying if will/will not be open at some point today? I don't know what happens in the case of the answer below when it is a trading day but outside of trading hours i.e. market closed but is a trading day. _if today the U.S. stock exchanges are open for trading_ implies only match required is trading should have occured that day.

Comment: Since your need is about "today" (and not historical dates), you can use the [NYSE page for market holidays](https://www.nyse.com/markets/hours-calendars). Parse the holdiays for the upcoming year at the beginning of every year. Save it to a file with readable format of your choice. And then retrieve that file and on top of that, exclude all weekends. Such is exactly what I do using Apps Script.

Answer (score 9):

With Python, the easiest way I have found is using the pandas_market_calendars library, which tells you the market days.

```
import pandas_market_calendars as mcal
nyse = mcal.get_calendar('NYSE')
nyse.valid_days(start_date='2016-12-20', end_date='2017-01-10')
```

Substitute start_date, end_date for yourself and generate the follow range.

```
DatetimeIndex(['2016-12-20 00:00:00+00:00', '2016-12-21 00:00:00+00:00',
               '2016-12-22 00:00:00+00:00', '2016-12-23 00:00:00+00:00',
               '2016-12-27 00:00:00+00:00', '2016-12-28 00:00:00+00:00',
               '2016-12-29 00:00:00+00:00', '2016-12-30 00:00:00+00:00',
               '2017-01-03 00:00:00+00:00', '2017-01-04 00:00:00+00:00',
               '2017-01-05 00:00:00+00:00', '2017-01-06 00:00:00+00:00',
               '2017-01-09 00:00:00+00:00', '2017-01-10 00:00:00+00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]', freq='C')
```

Check that the date today is in there.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using [Tradier's API](https://documentation.tradier.com/brokerage-api/markets/get-calendar) to do this in my shell scripts, then using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to get the status for a particular day.

```
date="your date"
month=$(date -d $date +%-m)
year=$(date -d $date +%Y)
calendar=$(curl -H "Authorization: Bearer "$tradierApi"" -H "Accept: application/json" "https://production-api.tradier.com/v1/markets/calendar?month="$month"&year="$year)
marketStatus=$(echo $calendar | ./jq-linux64 '.calendar.days.day[] | select(.date == "'$date'") | .status')
```

Answer (score 3):

As a previous answer mentioned, you can use `pandas-market-calendars`, and here's a simplified implementation based on the NYSE:

```py
import pandas_market_calendars as mcal
from datetime import datetime

def market_is_open(date):
    result = mcal.get_calendar("NYSE").schedule(start_date=date, end_date=date)
    return result.empty == False

# check if market is open today
is_open = market_is_open(datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))

# check if market was open 2023-04-16 (False)
was_open = market_is_open('2023-04-16')
```

Answer (score 2):

Until something more elegant and reliable turns up, I might use

```
curl -s "https://www.isthemarketopen.com/" |grep -c "** Stock market is closed"
```

which returns a 1 in today's case (Good Friday)--and I can directly use in conditional code--but has to be maintained and checked periodically how that URL's underlying HTML source may have changed.

Comment: Easter Monday morning, http://isthemarketopen.com is still publishing U.S. markets are closed due to Good Friday :( This breaks my code in the reverse case. Looking for alternatives for a quick single-line test.

Answer (score 2):

MSN quotes include a property indicating if the stock listing's market is open or closed:

https://www.msn.com/en-us/money/stockdetails/nas-aapl/fi-a1mou2?symbol=AAPL&form=PRMFPS

Below is an example Python script to get the status using the [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) parser.

If you're worried about them changing their css, I suppose a regex might be more reliable, etc.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

session = requests.session()

response = session.get('https://www.msn.com/en-us/money/stockdetails/nas-aapl/fi-a1mou2?symbol=AAPL&form=PRMFPS')

if response.status_code == 200:

    page = response.text
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")

    market = soup.find('span', attrs={'class': 'market-status-text'}).text

    if market == 'US Markets Closed':

       # do stuff

        print('closed')

    else:

        print('open')

        # do different stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a [Google Calendar](http://icalshare.com/calendars/6997) of the USA market holidays which is reasonably updated for the next several years.

As much as I hate to add a separate answer, this is a much better solution than the brittle URL page text-searcher before (which btw, two weeks later is still returning "** Stock market is closed Good Friday 4/19/19" instead of simply having "market is open today" somewhere).

First the code: (Ruby w/ embedded Bash)

```
$marketCal = %x'curl -s "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/2jpqg4chp4djba5ea99b22b838@group.calendar.google.com/events?key=[YOUR GOOGLE API KEY]&maxResults=1&timeMin=#{today=`date +%Y-%m-%d`.chomp}T00%3A00%3A01%2B00%3A00&timeMax=#{today}T23%3A59%3A59%2B00%3A00&"'

$isMarketOpenToday = $marketCal !~ /"status":/  # => true  when there exists event "id":, etc.
```

Since there are resource limits, you'll need to go and create your own free API key at
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?

The global variable **$isMarketOpenToday** yields **true** if there *isn't* a market holiday today, **false** otherwise.  Note that it doesn't consider day of the week, so on weekends it may still yield true.  So, just make that another simple test, if you need.  Eg. `[[ $(date +%u) < 6 ]] && echo "Weekday, yay!"`

A lot could be improved with programming standards; the goal here was simply to test the API with minimal lines of code easily checked from the CLI outside a script, however nasty.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell:

```
function isMarketOpen(){
    $url = "https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/quote?symbols=MSFT"
    try{
        $response = Invoke-RestMethod $url
        #return $response.quoteResponse.result[0]
        if($response.quoteResponse.result[0].marketState -eq 'CLOSED'){
            return $false
        }else{
            return $true
        }
    }catch{
        $_.exception | Write-Warning
        return $null
    }
}

isMarketOpen
```

Comment: Good, so the marketState of this JSON output on any ticker symbol.  I've yet to check if this will give "OPEN" on a trading day, but well before or after typical market hours.